# One database to hold SP for other databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

We currently have 3 web products. All 3 products are nearly identical, other than branding (verticalized for different industries). Currently, due to logistical need, we have 3 separate - nearly identical - databases (We'll call them Database A, Database B, and Database C). We need the databases to be separate for data segregation (this is a non negotiable issue).

Our current workflow when updating, creating, deleting stored procedures is to do it in one of the databases and then change the "Use Database A" to "Use Database B" and click run, then the same for Database C. This makes the store procedure on all three databases the same. This isn't too bad, but we are faced with a new problem.

We now have some high level corporate clients that would like to 'white label' our product and have their own databases to store their data separately. We could do this in the same fashion, but eventually with enough databases this will be incredibly cumbersome.

Is there any way to have one database that holds all the stored procedures and have them interact with the tables relevant to whichever database called the procedure? I know I can create SP_ procedures in the master table, and feed them a database name parameter, then inject that into dynamic SQL, but I dont want to have to convert all our stored procedures to dynamic SQL (There are tons of them and I don't like using dynamic SQL when I dont have to). Alternatively, is there a way to automate the process of applying stored procedure changes across the board to all databases?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle "run the exact same script over and over" on different servers/databases is to get familiar with the sqlcmd.exe way of doing things.

1. Create a file call "MyBatFile.bat" in a some folder.

Put this in the file:

```
set __sqlcmdexe=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE
set __sqlcmdexe=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE




"%__sqlcmdexe%" -S Server001\Instance001-i .\MyVersionSample.sql -o MyOutput_Server001_Instance001_Northwind.txt -v MyDatabaseName="Northwind" FavoriteColor="Red" MyErrorLog="MyErrorLog001.txt"
"%__sqlcmdexe%" -S Server001\Instance001-i .\MyVersionSample.sql -o MyOutput_Server001_Instance001_DoesNotExistDB.txt -v MyDatabaseName="DoesNotExistDB" FavoriteColor="Green" MyErrorLog="MyErrorLog002.txt"


set __sqlcmdexe=
```

Adjust the values "Server001" and "Instance001" (instance name, if applicable) to match something on your environment.  I used "Northwind" as a real db name.  Put in some (real) database name that you have.
Obviously, make sure you have a correct path to sqlcmd.exe on your machine.

1. In the same directory, create a file called "MyVersionSample.sql".

Put this in it:

```
/*
: s e tvar MyDatabaseName "Northwind"
*/

:Error $(MyErrorLog)


Use [$(MyDatabaseName)]
GO

print 'You passed in a variable'
print '$(FavoriteColor)'
print ''

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = N'$(MyDatabaseName)')
BEGIN
    print 'Database does not exist!!'
    print '$(MyDatabaseName)'
    print ''    
END


Select @@VERSION


GO
```

This simple example does a Select @@Version. Fairly benign.  But it will demonstrate.

1. Bring up a command line.  Run the file "MyBatFile.bat"....

You'll now get some log files.  Maybe an error file.

Basically, it will run the same script over and over against the environment and database you setup in the bat file.  And you get some log files.

The .sql itself has to be "sqlcmd"'ish.  It's not alot of work.

when testing your scripts, if you go to "Query : SqlCmdMode"  (where Query is a menu item like "File and Edit"....you can enter into sqlcmd mode.

Note in my example, you'll see this code.

```
/*
: s e tvar MyDatabaseName "Northwind"
*/
```

if you uncomment that and take out some spaces,to make it this:

```
:setvar MyDatabaseName "Northwind"
```

(reminder you need to be in sqlcmdMODE)..you can now test your script.

BE WARNED:  If you setvar something in code, it will overwrite the value you pass in from the .bat file with the -v flag.
This is documented here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/382007/in-sqlcmd-scripts-setvar-should-have-a-lower-precedence-than-command-line-variable-assignments

This is why I both commented out that part, and put some spaces in the :servar to make sure it doesn't override the values being passed in via the -v switch.

Boo to microsoft for not fixing it.

But this is the best way to do the same script over and over.  with some simple log files.
(IMHO).

I had a project where I had to create 24 databases (same DDL/schema) with filegroups, files, alot of stuff...........and I was able to whip them out within minutes......using this system.  and logfiles for stuff that didn't go right.

This is a great way to get predictable results...and not accidentally missing something.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

We store our SP source in source control (TFS) and have a bit of scripting written to extract the SPs based on adjustable criteria then append them together into file(s) for application to the database(s) of choice.  I'm reasonably sure a bit more meta work would let us set server & database info to have them applied across a set of databases without intervention, at least as long as everything compiles OK.

There are third-party tools like Red Gate (I've never used them) that will extract schema and prepare script files for you.  So you could theoretically maintain a "master schema" database and use that kind of thing to extract the current state for application elsewhere.

Comment: You should look into [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx), which is a free download for Visual Studio. SSDT (previously known as Data Dude) basically gives you the same functionality as the Red Gate tools (schema compare, data compare, etc.), and with the integration in Visual Studio, it is very easy to apply source control to all your SQL objects.

Comment: What I describe is the direction our database folks have chosen. I don't necessarily agree with them, and *do* have SSDT on my workstation. They're kind of Luddites when it comes to automation and anything other than custom-written tooling.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I prefer the TFS solution, we use it ourselves at work.

But, if you really want to go the way of stored procedures in master database (which I would advise against), then naming your procs with sp_ is just a part of solution. The other part is running the proc in current database's context. To achieve that, you have to mark the procedure as a system object.

Here's how to do it:

```
use master
go

create procedure dbo.sp_test
as
select db_name()
select * from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
go

EXEC sys.sp_MS_marksystemobject sp_Test
GO

use AdventureWorks2012
go

exec sp_test
go

use master
go

drop procedure sp_test
go
```

Keep in mind it's not supported. But OTOH could be extremely convenient :)

Answer (score 0):

Like DaveE suggests, keep your stored procs in version control. That's just good practice.

Here are some suggestions if you want to update multiple targets in one go:

1) Use Registered Servers in SSMS. Each target database can be created as a Registered Server within a Server Group. You can then right click on the Server Group and select "New Query". This query will execute against all Registered Servers in the Group. [This is explained in detail on MSSQLTips](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2855/sql-server-multi-database-query-with-registered-servers/).

2) [SQL Multi Script](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/) is a dedicated tool we developed at Red Gate to satisfy this use case.